# How i change console application project to windows form app. project

Tags: c#, process, console, mutex, pid

I made a console application project for my project but its console application so how I change it to Form application... can anyone help me to change this console application to Windows form application.

Who know change console application codes to form application codes.

Please help me.. i want put "static void Main(string[] args) "codes in a button..

```
public class Win32API
{
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    public static extern int NtQueryObject(IntPtr ObjectHandle, int
        ObjectInformationClass, IntPtr ObjectInformation, int ObjectInformationLength,
        ref int returnLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    public static extern uint NtQuerySystemInformation(int
        SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, int SystemInformationLength,
        ref int returnLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenMutex(UInt32 desiredAccess, bool inheritHandle, string name);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool DuplicateHandle(IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
       ushort hSourceHandle, IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle, out IntPtr lpTargetHandle,
       uint dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bInheritHandle, uint dwOptions);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    public enum ObjectInformationClass : int
    {
        ObjectBasicInformation = 0,
        ObjectNameInformation = 1,
        ObjectTypeInformation = 2,
        ObjectAllTypesInformation = 3,
        ObjectHandleInformation = 4
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
    {
        All = 0x001F0FFF,
        Terminate = 0x00000001,
        CreateThread = 0x00000002,
        VMOperation = 0x00000008,
        VMRead = 0x00000010,
        VMWrite = 0x00000020,
        DupHandle = 0x00000040,
        SetInformation = 0x00000200,
        QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
        Synchronize = 0x00100000
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION
    { // Information Class 0
        public int Attributes;
        public int GrantedAccess;
        public int HandleCount;
        public int PointerCount;
        public int PagedPoolUsage;
        public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
        public int Reserved1;
        public int Reserved2;
        public int Reserved3;
        public int NameInformationLength;
        public int TypeInformationLength;
        public int SecurityDescriptorLength;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreateTime;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION
    { // Information Class 2
        public UNICODE_STRING Name;
        public int ObjectCount;
        public int HandleCount;
        public int Reserved1;
        public int Reserved2;
        public int Reserved3;
        public int Reserved4;
        public int PeakObjectCount;
        public int PeakHandleCount;
        public int Reserved5;
        public int Reserved6;
        public int Reserved7;
        public int Reserved8;
        public int InvalidAttributes;
        public GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;
        public int ValidAccess;
        public byte Unknown;
        public byte MaintainHandleDatabase;
        public int PoolType;
        public int PagedPoolUsage;
        public int NonPagedPoolUsage;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION
    { // Information Class 1
        public UNICODE_STRING Name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct UNICODE_STRING
    {
        public ushort Length;
        public ushort MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr Buffer;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GENERIC_MAPPING
    {
        public int GenericRead;
        public int GenericWrite;
        public int GenericExecute;
        public int GenericAll;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION
    { // Information Class 16
        public int ProcessID;
        public byte ObjectTypeNumber;
        public byte Flags; // 0x01 = PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE, 0x02 = INHERIT
        public ushort Handle;
        public int Object_Pointer;
        public UInt32 GrantedAccess;
    }

    public const int MAX_PATH = 260;
    public const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xC0000004;
    public const int DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 0x2;
    public const int DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE = 0x1;
}

public class Win32Processes
{
    const int CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = 16;
    const uint STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = 0xc0000004;

    public static string getObjectTypeName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
    {
        IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
        IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
        IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
        var objObjectType = new Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION();
        IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
        string strObjectTypeName = "";
        int nLength = 0;
        int nReturn = 0;
        IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle,
                                      Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle,
                                      0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
            return null;

        ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
        Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                               ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
        objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);

        ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objBasic.TypeInformationLength);
        nLength = objBasic.TypeInformationLength;
        while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
            ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectTypeInformation, ipObjectType,
              nLength, ref nLength)) ==
            Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
            ipObjectType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        }

        objObjectType = (Win32API.OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectType, objObjectType.GetType());
        if (Is64Bits())
        {
            ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectType.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
        }
        else
        {
            ipTemp = objObjectType.Name.Buffer;
        }

        strObjectTypeName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ipTemp, objObjectType.Name.Length >> 1);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectType);
        return strObjectTypeName;
    }


    public static string getObjectName(Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle, Process process)
    {
        IntPtr m_ipProcessHwnd = Win32API.OpenProcess(Win32API.ProcessAccessFlags.All, false, process.Id);
        IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        var objBasic = new Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION();
        IntPtr ipBasic = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr ipObjectType = IntPtr.Zero;
        var objObjectName = new Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION();
        IntPtr ipObjectName = IntPtr.Zero;
        string strObjectName = "";
        int nLength = 0;
        int nReturn = 0;
        IntPtr ipTemp = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(m_ipProcessHwnd, shHandle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(),
                                      out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS))
            return null;

        ipBasic = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic));
        Win32API.NtQueryObject(ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectBasicInformation,
                               ipBasic, Marshal.SizeOf(objBasic), ref nLength);
        objBasic = (Win32API.OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipBasic, objBasic.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipBasic);


        nLength = objBasic.NameInformationLength;

        ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        while ((uint)(nReturn = Win32API.NtQueryObject(
                 ipHandle, (int)Win32API.ObjectInformationClass.ObjectNameInformation,
                 ipObjectName, nLength, ref nLength))
               == Win32API.STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
            ipObjectName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        }
        objObjectName = (Win32API.OBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipObjectName, objObjectName.GetType());

        if (Is64Bits())
        {
            ipTemp = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(objObjectName.Name.Buffer.ToString(), 10) >> 32);
        }
        else
        {
            ipTemp = objObjectName.Name.Buffer;
        }

        if (ipTemp != IntPtr.Zero)
        {

            byte[] baTemp2 = new byte[nLength];
            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(ipTemp, baTemp2, 0, nLength);

                strObjectName = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Is64Bits() ?
                                                       new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt64()) :
                                                       new IntPtr(ipTemp.ToInt32()));
                return strObjectName;
            }
            catch (AccessViolationException)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipObjectName);
                Win32API.CloseHandle(ipHandle);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>
    GetHandles(Process process = null, string IN_strObjectTypeName = null, string IN_strObjectName = null)
    {
        uint nStatus;
        int nHandleInfoSize = 0x10000;
        IntPtr ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nHandleInfoSize);
        int nLength = 0;
        IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        while ((nStatus = Win32API.NtQuerySystemInformation(CNST_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION, ipHandlePointer,
                                                            nHandleInfoSize, ref nLength)) ==
                STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            nHandleInfoSize = nLength;
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandlePointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nLength);
        }

        byte[] baTemp = new byte[nLength];
        Marshal.Copy(ipHandlePointer, baTemp, 0, nLength);

        long lHandleCount = 0;
        if (Is64Bits())
        {
            lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt64(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt64() + 8);
        }
        else
        {
            lHandleCount = Marshal.ReadInt32(ipHandlePointer);
            ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandlePointer.ToInt32() + 4);
        }

        Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION shHandle;
        List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION> lstHandles = new List<Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION>();

        for (long lIndex = 0; lIndex < lHandleCount; lIndex++)
        {
            shHandle = new Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION();
            if (Is64Bits())
            {
                shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle) + 8);
            }
            else
            {
                ipHandle = new IntPtr(ipHandle.ToInt64() + Marshal.SizeOf(shHandle));
                shHandle = (Win32API.SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ipHandle, shHandle.GetType());
            }

            if (process != null)
            {
                if (shHandle.ProcessID != process.Id) continue;
            }

            string strObjectTypeName = "";
            if (IN_strObjectTypeName != null){
                 strObjectTypeName = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                if (strObjectTypeName != IN_strObjectTypeName) continue;
            }

            string strObjectName = "";
            if (IN_strObjectName != null){
                 strObjectName = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
                if (strObjectName != IN_strObjectName) continue;
            }

            string strObjectTypeName2 = getObjectTypeName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
            string strObjectName2 = getObjectName(shHandle, Process.GetProcessById(shHandle.ProcessID));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}   {2}", shHandle.ProcessID, strObjectTypeName2, strObjectName2);

            lstHandles.Add(shHandle);
        }
        return lstHandles;
    }

    public static bool Is64Bits()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8 ? true : false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String MutexName = "MSCTF.Asm.MutexDefault1";
        String ProcessName = "notepad";

        try
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcessName)[0];
            var handles = Win32Processes.GetHandles(process, "Mutant", "\\Sessions\\1\\BaseNamedObjects\\" + MutexName);
            if (handles.Count == 0) throw new System.ArgumentException("NoMutex", "original");
            foreach (var handle in handles)
            {
                IntPtr ipHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!Win32API.DuplicateHandle(Process.GetProcessById(handle.ProcessID).Handle, handle.Handle, Win32API.GetCurrentProcess(), out ipHandle, 0, false, Win32API.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE))
                    Console.WriteLine("DuplicateHandle() failed, error = {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                Console.WriteLine("Mutex was killed");
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process name '{0}' is not currently running", ProcessName);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Mutex '{0}' was not found in the process '{1}'", MutexName, ProcessName);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, in order for the community to be able to help you please share what you have tried doing or some code that the community can review.

Comment: The mutant\...\Growtopia is most likely a memory mapped file or shared memory. So the actual question might be how to delete a memory mapped file or shared memory.

Comment: Can help me? someone said me its a mutex how i kill mutex?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project using the Visual Studio "New Project' dialogue and select:

`C# Windows Form App (.NET Framework)`

Go to the designer and add a button, which can be found in the toolbox.

Then add a button click event handler, put your code inside the button click event handler.

Here's a 3 minute [video](https://youtu.be/XK0xXQtyt_U) showing you how to do it